# Akka http file streaming not writing bytes more than 'n' size from different clients

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

```
`Akka http 10.0.6;
 max-content-length is set to 6000m`
```

I am using Akka file streaming to upload huge files( sent as octet-stream to my service ) to accept incoming bytes and write it to a file sink. This is what I observe from my experimentations.. My limited understand from reading the documents is the client should be able keep sending the data unless we tell explicitly from akka http for back pressure mechanisms.. Been searching online to understand this behavior, not able to get an understanding yet on this to explain the following behavior.. Is there something I am missing in the code? How can I debug more on this? Also, via scalatest, able to do it. If someone can throw more might on what’s the difference in behavior w.r.t scalatest and via curl/http clients.. Thanks

1. Through "**curl**", I can stream **max of 1KB** sized file. Anything more than this, it will just hang and this message is given after timeout no matter how long I wait(20 seconds, 5 mins, 10 mins, etc) "Sending an 2xx 'early' response before end of request was received... Note that the connection will be closed after this response. Also, many clients will not read early responses! Consider only issuing this response after the request data has been completely read!"
2. Through "**Apache http client**", **max of 128KB** sized file streaming happens. Anything more than this, it will hang and same message as in #1 from akka http service
3. Through "**python client**", **max of ~26KB** sized file streaming happens. Anything more than this, it will hang and same message as in #1 from akka http service
4. Through **scalatest** inside the service, was able to upload files like **200MB, 400MB and more also**

Here’s the code..

```
`put {
   withoutSizeLimit {
       extractDataBytes { bytes =>          
           implicit val system = ActorSystem()     
           implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
           // Tried system dispatcher also
           implicit val executionContext = system.dispatchers.lookup("dispatcher")
           val sink = FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("/file.out"))
           val action = bytes.runWith(sink).map {
                case ior if ior.wasSuccessful => {     
                  complete(StatusCodes.OK, s"${ior.count} bytes written")     
                }
                case ior => complete(StatusCodes.EnhanceYourCalm, ior.getError.toString)     
                }
           Await.result(action, 300.seconds)     
      }
   }
 }`
```

Comment: I don't think it's related to your question but you should definitely move the actorsystem, materializer, and executioncontext creation outside of the route logic.

Comment: Thanks Ramon. I have it actually outside the route in the package object. Just for illustration, showed in the same code